# Changing Date format in MySql

Tags: python, mysql, database

I have a large Csv file that I wanna  bulk-load it to my table. A column of this csv file keeps the dates but in the DD-MM-YYYY format. When I am loading this file to my table, it does not accept it, since MySQL DATE format only accepts YYYY-MM-DD. Is there any way I could change this in MySQL. I am using python to create my tables and to load my file into the table, which doesn't matter for this problem actually.If there is a command for this, please tell me where I should put it exactly?
thanks
This is the complete code

```
import MySQLdb,os

path='data_files'
absPath = os.path.abspath(path)
print absPath


#connecting to the new database
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
                          user='root',
                          passwd='',
                          db='iens')

db_cursor = conn.cursor()

query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '"+ absPath + "/recencies" +"' INTO TABLE iens.recensies FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (restaurantID,Naam,Date,RecensieText) "

db_cursor.execute(query)

conn.commit()
```

Comment: Show us your code which loads this data into the table and has a problem with date format.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wanna

Comment: I didn't think it was English.   Why can't you simply use "want to"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your table has two columns named `column1` and `column2`, the date is in `column2` and that is the second column in the CSV file:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename' (column1, @var1)
SET column2 = STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%d-%m-%Y')
```

The `(column1, @var1)` part says:

- The first column of the CSV file goes directly into the database column `column1`
- The second column of the CSV file goes into a variable `@var1`

The `SET column2 =` part says:

- Set the database column `column2` to whatever comes out of the expression following the `=` sign.

Comment: is it possible to show me how to do this on my own code? thanks

Comment: I added some explanations. I hope this helps you in figuring out how to apply this to your code.

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL Reference Manual :: Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) -- see `STR_TO_DATE` to convert a string to a date.

Comment: But can you use that in LOAD DATA INFILE?